# The Irwin-Hall Distribution with a different parameter

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

Many of you would know of the Irwin-Hall distribution which states that if you have $n$ independent and identically distributed $U(0,1)$ variables, $U_1, U_2, U_3 \cdots$ and let $X = \sum_{i=1}^{n} U_i$, then the probability density of function of $X$ is: $${\displaystyle f_{X}(x;n)={\frac {1}{2(n-1)!}}\sum _{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}{n \choose k}(x-k)^{n-1}\operatorname {sgn}(x-k)}.$$

Is there something similar that gives the cumulative density function of $X$? Also, is there a way to change the parameter for the variables to make it so that they are uniformly distributed from $(-1, 1)$?

Answer (score 3):

Refer to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution) for the CDF, which is

$$F_X(x) = \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} (x-k)^n.$$

As for your second question, this is something you can derive yourself via a suitable transformation, namely if $X \sim \operatorname{IrwinHall}(0,n)$, we have $$Y = 2X-n,$$ thus $X = g^{-1}(Y) = \frac{Y+n}{2}$ and $$f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \left|\frac{dg^{-1}}{dy}\right| = \frac{1}{2} f_X(\tfrac{y+n}{2}),$$ where the density $f_X$ is the formula you provided.

Comment: what does $g^{-1}(Y)$ mean? Also, why isn't $f_Y(y) = f_X(\frac{y+1}{2})$? Where did the $\left|\frac{dg^{-1}}{dy}\right|$ even come from? What does that mean?

Comment: @delhimaths $Y = g(X) = 2X-1$, where $g$ is the monotone transformation function.  $g^{-1}$ is the inverse transformation.  This is a formula that is well-known and elementary; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Functions_of_random_variables

Comment: so in this case, would $F_Y(y) = F_X(\frac{x+1}{2})$ since $g^{-1} = \frac{x+1}{2}$ is increasing?

Comment: @delhimaths That is correct.

Comment: wait something seems wrong here though. Let's say I wanted to calculate $F_Y(-1)$ and let's assume I'm summing $2$ variables. Since each $Y$ is chosen from $[-1, 1]$, this probability is obviously $>0$. However, when you plug it in, you get $F_X(0)$. But since each of the random variables ranges from $[0,1]$, this probability becomes $0$. This is an obvious flaw. What is wrong?

Comment: @delhimaths I made a simple error which I have fixed.  The issue is that $X$ is the sum of $n$ uniform $(0,1)$ variables, thus its support is on $(0,n)$.  If $Y$ is a sum of uniform $(-1,1)$ variables, then its support is on $(-n,n)$.  So the appropriate transformation is $Y = g(X) = 2X - n$, not $2X - 1$.